# Magento2 Get Customer Custom session Data in Javascript file

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript

I am trying to get the custom session data of Customer in a javascript file. As I am passing `'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'` as dependency in order to retrieve the data.

```
define(
[
    ......
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    .....
],
function (Component,customerData) {
    'use strict';



    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Mymodule_Company/myTemplate'
        },
        initialize : function(){
           this._super(customerData.getData());
           console.log(customerData.getCustomerInfo());
        }
    });
}
);
```

I want to get a custom variable just like i set up in my php file :

```
$this->customerSession->setMyCustomValue("my custom variable");
```

Comment: Did you mange to get it work?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you want, if you want like the cart section you could use it in the following way:

```
customerData.get('cart')();
```

You could add custom data to the customer data and then retrieve it with like:

```
customerData.get('sectionData');
```

More info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html